# Authenticate Google Sign in from app with .NET backend server

Tags: .net, google-api

I'm allowing users to sign into Google via an iOS app. Next step is confirming that they did indeed sign in, when they make requests to my backend server.

[This article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth) has a section at [the bottom](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library) explaining that I can use an official Google API client library to validate a sign in.

I'm struggling to see how I can achieve this with the .NET client library, as they don't include examples for this.

Is anyone able to shed some light as to how this can be done with the .NET client library?

Comment: Take a look here, maybe will be helpful:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973744/validate-google-id-against-a-net-backend-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973744/validate-google-id-against-a-net-backend-server)

Answer (score 0):

.Net Google API Client Library repository: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client