# validate Google ID against a .net backend server

Tags: .net, google-signin

Im trying to implement google sign in for my app.

The backend server will be c# .net....

Can Some point me in the direction, or explain how to do the backend verification in .Net... they have provided java examples and suggest using googles apis

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem.
What you need on server side is to verify 'id token' you got on client side.
So, first on client side you get the 'id token' via:

```
function onGoogleSignIn(googleUser)
{
    //Here call ajax and pass googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
}
```

Ok, now on server side you can use the following function in order to verify the token:

```
public sealed class JWTCertificateUrl
{
    private JWTCertificateUrl(string value) { Value = value; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static JWTCertificateUrl Google { get { return new JWTCertificateUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"); } }
}

public sealed class JWTIssuer
{
    private JWTIssuer(string value) { Value = value; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static JWTIssuer None { get { return new JWTIssuer(""); } }
    public static JWTIssuer Google { get { return new JWTIssuer("accounts.google.com"); } }
}

public static class Utils
{
    private const string beginCert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\\n";
    private const string endCert = "\\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\\n";
    private static byte[][] getCertBytes(JWTCertificateUrl certificate)
    {
        // The request will be made to the authentication server.
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(certificate.Value);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        String[] split = responseFromServer.Split(':');

        // There are two certificates returned from Google
        byte[][] certBytes = new byte[2][];
        int index = 0;
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
            if (split[i].IndexOf(beginCert) > 0)
            {
                int startSub = split[i].IndexOf(beginCert);
                int endSub = split[i].IndexOf(endCert) + endCert.Length;
                certBytes[index] = utf8.GetBytes(split[i].Substring(startSub, endSub).Replace("\\n", "\n"));
                index++;
            }
        }
        return certBytes;
    }

    public static bool CheckJWTToken(JWTCertificateUrl cert, JWTIssuer tokenIssuer, string appId, string idToken, ref Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        if (data == null)
            data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idToken))
            return false;

        //JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(idToken);
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler jsth = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        Byte[][] certBytes = getCertBytes(cert);
        Dictionary<String, X509Certificate2> certificates = new Dictionary<String, X509Certificate2>();
        for (int i = 0; i < certBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certBytes[i]);
            certificates.Add(certificate.Thumbprint, certificate);
        }

        TokenValidationParameters tvp = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateActor = false, // check the profile ID

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = appId,

            ValidateIssuer = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenIssuer.Value),
            ValidIssuer = tokenIssuer.Value,

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (s, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
            {
                return identifier.Select(x =>
                {
                    if (certificates.ContainsKey(x.Id.ToUpper()))
                    {
                        return new X509SecurityKey(certificates[x.Id.ToUpper()]);
                    }
                    return null;
                }).First(x => x != null);
            },
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300) //5 minutes
        };

        bool res = false;
        try
        {
            // Validate using the provider
            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            ClaimsPrincipal cp = jsth.ValidateToken(idToken, tvp, out validatedToken);
            if (cp != null)
            {
                foreach (var claim in cp.Claims)
                {
                    var name = claim.Type;
                    //Delete the URL part just for convenient
                    if (name.StartsWith("http"))
                        name = name.Remove(0, name.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    data.Add(name, claim.Value);
                }
                res = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Function call:

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = null;
if (Utils.CheckJWTToken(JWTCertificateUrl.Google, JWTIssuer.Google, "[your google app id].apps.googleusercontent.com", idToken, ref data))
{
  //Here you can take user data for further process
  //data["emailaddress"], data["givenname"], data["surname"]
}
```

In order to compile the code you'll need to install .NET JWT library from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/

The code above was taken here: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-csharp

Comment: It's worth noting that the Nuget package this depends on requires you to be on .NET 4.5, so doesn't suit any project operating on a lower version of the framework. If you need an easy alternative and can't upgrade to .NET 4.5, I found it was simpler to use a REST library such as RestSharp to implement the logic walked through at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint, using Google's own end point to validate the token and my .NET application no longer required any knowledge of JWT tokens. This was a satisfactory workaround.